# Showing continuity by the inverse image of every open set is open for addition and product function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

Here are the 2 questions:

> [image]

I am wondering how can I Show continuity by using the following definition of continuity: the inverse image of every open set is open. could anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Question tells you to draw the pre-image, I think it's quite obvious if you follow the instruction.

Q1:

It's a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (See the following figure)

[image]

So no matter how you choose $(a,b)$, for each $m\in(a,b)$ the preimage of it will be the line $y=-x+m$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus the preimage of the whole interval is the area between $y=-x+a$ and $y=-x+b$ (i.e. doesn't contain the two boundary lines). Now, consider a sequence $(x_n)\in \sigma^{-1}((a,b)^C)$ converging to $x\in \sigma^{-1}((a,b)^C)$. Suppose not, then since $x_n\to x$, we can find $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$ which means this sequence is in $\sigma^{-1}((a,b))$ contradicts our assumption, so $x\in \sigma^{-1}((a,b)^C))$ therefore $\sigma^{-1}((a,b))^C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2\implies\sigma^{-1}((a,b))$ is open.

Q2: Similarly, follow the instruction, the preimage $\mu^{-1}((a,b))$ lies between two hyperbolas $xy=a$ and $xy=b$, using the same method, you can prove its continuity.

Comment: does $m$ need to be in $(a,b)$?

Comment: I said $m\in(a,b)$, I mentioned this because I tried to find an expression for a preimage and hence express the sets in this form. @Secretly

Comment: How does this   $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$  means that this sequence is in $\sigma^{-1}((a,b))$ ?

Comment: @Mathstupid  $x$ lies between $-x+a$ and $-x+b$, and we can find points of this sequence that are arbitrarily close to $x$, and since it doesn’t contain those two lines, those points must lies in the perimage, but we have assumed that $x_n$ is in the complement of that pre image.

Answer (score 3):

If $(x_0,y_0)\in\sigma^{-1}(J)$ or equivalently $a<x_0+y_0<b$ then you can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $a<x+y<b$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ and $|y-y_0|<\epsilon$.

This means that the open set $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)\times(y_0-\epsilon,y_0+\epsilon)\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ contains $(x_0,y_0)$ and is a subset of $\sigma^{-1}(J)$.

Here $(x_0,y_0)$ is an *arbitrary* element of $\sigma^{-1}(J)$ so actually it has been shown that for *every* $(x,y)\in\sigma^{-1}(J)$ we can find a set $U_{(x,y)}$ open in $\mathbb R^2$ and satisfying $(x,y)\in U_{(x,y)}\subseteq\sigma^{-1}(J)$.

Then we can conclude that: $$\bigcup_{(x,y)\in\sigma^{-1}(J)}U_{(x,y)}=\sigma^{-1}(J)$$where the LHS is a union of open sets.

This justifies the conclusion that $\sigma^{-1}(J)$ is open.

This can be proved for every open interval $J$ so we are allowed to conclude that $\sigma$ is continuous.

---

The same principle can be applied in order to prove that $\mu$ is continuous.

Comment: Is this "equivalently $a<x_0+y_0<b$ then you can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $a<x+y<b$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ and $|y-y_0|<\epsilon$."by Archemidian property?

Comment: @Mathstupid Writing that down I did not have things in mind as the Archemidian property but only $\mathbb R$ equipped with metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. But the topology induced by this metric coincides with the order topology on $\mathbb R$ and in that context you can say (I think) indeed that it rests on Archemidian property.

Comment: In the third line, is it $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Mathstupid Yes, thank you for attending me. Repaired now.

Comment: I do not understand the importance of the first 2 lines in your solution. could you please explain their importance?

Comment: I think also in the sixth line it should be $\mathbb R^2$ instead.

Comment: what is the importance of $x,y$ in the first 2 lines?

Comment: It is stated there that for some $\epsilon>0$ and some arbitrary point $(x,y)$ we have $(x,y)\in\sigma^{-1}(J)$ whenever $x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ and $y\in(y_0-\epsilon,y_0+\epsilon)$. In other words that $$(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)\times(y_0-\epsilon,y_0+\epsilon)\subseteq\sigma^{-1}(J)$$