# Understanding a solution in showing continuity by the inverse image of every open set is open for addition.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Here is the link:

[Showing continuity by the inverse image of every open set is open for addition and product function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541237/showing-continuity-by-the-inverse-image-of-every-open-set-is-open-for-addition-a)

But I did not understand (the detailed proof) for the following:

"If $(x_0,y_0)\in\sigma^{-1}(J)$ or equivalently $a<x_0+y_0<b$ then we can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $a<x+y<b$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ and $|y-y_0|<\epsilon$" how can we find this $\epsilon$ is it  by Archimedian property? if so how? could anyone explain this for me please?

This was mentioned in the second solution in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the Archimedian property.

Take $r>0$ such that $a<x_0+y_0-r<x_0+y_0+r<b$. Now, thake $\varepsilon=\frac r2$. Then, if $\lvert x-x_0\rvert,\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\varepsilon$, then\begin{align}\lvert(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)\rvert&\leqslant\lvert x-x_0\rvert+\lvert y-y_0\rvert\\&<\frac r2+\frac r2\\&=r.\end{align}and therefore$$a<x+y<b.$$

Comment: what is $x_x$ in the second line?

Comment: It was a typo. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I can not understand why the last two lines follows from the previous information. could you please explain in words?

Comment: Since $\lvert(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)\rvert<r$, $x+y\in(x_0+y_0-r,x_0+y_0+r)$. But I assumed that $(x_0+y_0-r,x_0+y_0+r)\subset(a,b)$. Therefore, $x+y\in(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $\epsilon =\frac  1 2\min \{(x_0+y_0)-a,b-(x_0+y_0)\}$. If $|x-x_0| <\epsilon $ and $|y-y_0| <\epsilon $ then  $|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)| <2\epsilon$. Now try to show from this that $x+y \in (a,b)$. [$x+y <x_0+y_0+2\epsilon <b$ etc].